# Is there any way to hide video src coming in vimeo embed url

Tags: javascript, php, video, vimeo, vimeo-player

I am displaying private Vimeo videos using Embed URL provided by vimeo at my site to users which can't be downloaded but users can find out the video url from src and able to download that Vimeo video. Is there any setting in Vimeo or any other player (tried with default vimeo player and flow player) available that can hide the video URL when video is being played in the player.

Comment: People can download it even if the URL is hidden by using some simple browser add-ons.

Comment: When they can watch it, they can download it. Don't you think the effect is the same? If you don't want they download, the only way is not showing to them.

Comment: Try to print out the <src..> code to the video on the server side, in PHP. If you echo the HTML that embeds the video they can't check the source code and find the video link. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR
Try to obfuscate

It's very difficult to prevent an user from downloading a video because of the various downloaders and plugins available to download an video in http protocol.

But there aren't that many plugins or downloaders available to download a video in rtmp protocol. Note: I am not saying that the video in rtmp can't be downloaded.

But it takes some time for the user to do research on what downloader or plugin he/she needs and sometimes he/she need to do an exhaustive set up. And second thing is the trust factor, most of the time people don't go and download any downloader that is available in the market.

As for the url's in the mark up. I know that there isn't any solution. Because when the user uses any debugger he can easily identify the Network resources.
But u can obfuscate the JavaScript and try to make sure that the user takes some time to identify the url.

https://jsfiddle.net/5b4dx9m0/

```
// encoder (140 chars)
eval(unescape(escape("").replace(/uD./g,'')))

// Decoder (124 chars)
eval(unescape(escape("").replace(/uD./g,'')))


// Test
str="Soleo saepe ante oculos ponere, idque libenter crebris usurpare sermonibus, omnis nostrorum imperatorum, omnis exterarum gentium potentissimorumque populorum, omnis clarissimorum regum res gestas, cum tuis nec contentionum magnitudine nec numero proeliorum nec varietate regionum nec celeritate conficiendi nec dissimilitudine bellorum posse conferri; nec vero disiunctissimas terras citius passibus."; // => 400 chars

console.log(e(str)); // => 140 chars

console.log(d(e(str))); // => 400 chars (same as str)
```